# mysql update in nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, express

I have written the code to upate the creditAmt and use that same creditAmt to increment the accountBal field.

Here is the code that I have tried:

```js
router.put('/', (req, res) = >{
  const {
    accountBal
  } = req.body;
  conn.query('UPDATE accounts SET creditAmt=accountBal WHERE accNum=?', (errors, resul) = >{
    if (errors) {
      return console.log(errors);
    } else {
      return res.send('Account credited');
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: and which question do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the parameters to the query:

```
router.put('/', (req, res) => {
  const { accountBal } = req.body;
  conn.query(
    'UPDATE accounts SET creditAmt = ? WHERE accNum = ?',
    [accountBal, <account-number>], // You will also need to provide the accNum
    (errors, resul) => {
      if (errors) {
        return console.log(errors);
      } else {
        return res.send('Account credited');
      }
    }
  );
});
```